# JavaScript: How do I take data from an array and create list in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

So I've got some code in JavaScript that takes the text from any subNav class  and places it in a single array.

```js
var subheading = []

var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('subNav');

for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) subheading.push(elements[i].textContent)

var navList = subheading.join()
```

However I'm stuck with then taking this text and putting it into a separate organised list in another div class e.g div sideNavBar.

```html
<p class="subNav">
    <a href"">Test 1</a>
</p>
<p class="subNav">
    <a href"">Test 2</a>
</p>    
<p class="subNav">
    <a href"">Test 3</a>
</p>
<p class="subNav">
    <a href"">Test 4</a>
</p>

<div class="sideNavBar">
</p>
```

The idea for this is to be able to put this into a fixed sidebar that can then be used to jump to anchors attached to subheadings as opposed to just having the links at the top of the page.

Could anyone suggest a function to create a list then place the data from my array into it?

Comment: Use a for-loop, and create html strings: '<p class="subNav"><a href="">'+arrVal[i]+'</a>' and keep adding to the string, then append to your element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Array.map()` is great for this:

```js
var arrOfStrings = ["Val1", "Val2", "Val3"]

var stringsAsNewMenu = arrOfStrings.map(val => `<li class="navItem">${val}</li>`).join("")

var menuElem = document.createElement('ul')

menuElem.innerHTML = stringsAsNewMenu

document.body.appendChild(menuElem)
```